# Requisição http post no ionic não envia os dados como x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: ionic, angular, http-request

Preciso realizar uma requisição http pra realizar login na minha aplicação ionic, porém minha função precisa enviar os dados como x-www-form-urlencoded, tentei de diversas maneiras diferentes mas ainda não consegui.

```
  public login(credenciais):Observable<any>{

    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('email', credenciais.email);
    formData.append('password', credenciais.password);

    return this._http.post<any>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'loginnovo',
    formData, {observe: 'response'
    }
  )
}
```

Desta maneira eu recebo:

> Http failure during parsing

Também tentei:

```
  public login(credenciais):Observable<any>{


    return this._http.post<any>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'loginnovo',
    {email: credenciais.password,
    password: credenciais.password},  
    {observe: 'response'
    }
  )
}
```

Dessa maneira recebo um Http failure during parsing
Se eu verificar no Request Payload, eu tenho:

{email: "email@gmail.com", password: "1234"}
email
:
"email@gmail.com"
password
:
"1234"

Comment: se enviares somente o objeto credenciais não funciona?

Comment: acredito que dessa maneira ele envia como form data, pois como retorno eu deveria receber algo no body, e eu recebo null. Quando testo pelo form-data no postman, eu também recebo nulo, quando troco pra x-www-formurlencoded eu recebo como retorno no body o email que uso pra fazer login, então suponho que eu ainda esteja enviando como form-data

Answer (score 0):

O `x-www-form-urlencoded` deve ser informado no header. Tente o seguinte:

```
public login(credenciais):Observable<any>{

    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('email', credenciais.email);
    formData.append('password', credenciais.password);

    let headerJson = {
        'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded',
    };
    let headers = new HttpHeaders(headerJson);

    return this._http.post<any>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'loginnovo',
        JSON.stringify(formData), {headers: this._headers});

}
```

Comment: Tentei mas ele cai no else do subscribe e mostra mensagem de erro. Se eu colocar console.log(error) ele retorna null

Comment: Se você estiver usando o `ionic serve --lab`, veja em Inspecionar - Network se o header está sendo enviado corretamente e qual é a resposta da requisição. Um problema comum é erro devido ao preflight.

Comment: estou usando ionic serve -c, dessa maneira que vc postou não está sendo enviado nenhum dado no Request Payload, está vazio.

Comment: Inclua também o Content-Type application/json no header e altere para `return this._http.post<any>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'loginnovo',      JSON.stringify({email: credenciais.password, password: credenciais.password}), {headers: this._headers});`

Comment: Alterei, mas recebo: Http failure during parsing

Comment: Vi uma possível solução em [https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18396](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18396), que é incluir `responseType: 'text'`. `return this._http.post<any>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'loginnovo', JSON.stringify({email: credenciais.password, password: credenciais.password}), {headers: this._headers, responseType: 'text'});`

Comment: Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: "text"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
    Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.

Answer (score 0):

Gente, eu consegui fazer a requisição desta maneira:

public login(credenciais):Observable{

```
return this._http.post<any>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'loginnovo',
{email: JSON.stringify(credenciais.email), password: credenciais.passowrd}, 
{observe: 'response'})
.pipe(
  map((response) => ({data: response.body, status: response.status}))
)
```

O problema estava no campo credenciais.email, então eu fiz JSON.stringify apenas no campo de email e funcionou. Não sei direito porquê o ionic me obriga a fazer isso, pois no angular funciona normal, enfim, se alguém tiver mais alguma informação sobre isso.